# Having stacked instances be "accessible"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript, instance, symbols

sorry about the bad title. So I am trying to have a box, with a number on it which will either be `1` or `3`. 
I would like the program to detect when either the box *or* the text has been clicked. 
I would prefer *not* to use an `if` statement saying `is (this has been tapped) && (this has been tapped)`.
I already tried setting the text as a dynamic text box, and saying

```
    if(this is true){
have this happen}
```

and then have the text box be part of the symbol, but I get the error:

```
1120: Access of undefined property [DYNAMIC TEXT BOX NAME].
```

I've also tried creating 2 instances for the two possible outputs in the text box, keeping them off screen, and then just teleporting the needed one *onto* the screen, but then I can only click *around* the text, not on it?

**What would be the best way to do this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "teleport" instances? You'd better employ `addChild()` and `removeChild()` approach, this way you declare a Sprite container, add two instance-wide variables of type `TextField` to it (or use one, just change the text, if this suits you), and assign an event listener to the container instance.

```
public class TextBox extends Sprite {
    private var tf:TextField;
    private var _value:int; // 1 or 3
    public function get value():int {return _value; }
    public function set value(v:int):void {
        tf.text=v;
        _value=v;
    } // this ensures that when you assign the value to a TextBox, the text field
    // will have the same text as the value
    public function TextBox() {
        // either assign a text field via Flash CS GUI or instantiate it here
    }
}
```

Then you make an instance of `TextBox`, place it somewhere and add an event listener of `TouchEvent.TOUCH_TAP` or `MouseEvent.CLICK` type, whatever your interface uses.

Another way to do the same is to use your existing text fields, but assign their `mouseEnabled` property to false, this should make Flash CS to pass mouse events to underlying box. This makes you do the least amount of effort, but is generally bad for your future growth as a programmer.

Comment: Unfortunately I programmed this in the action window, so I don't think I can add classes, nor do I have any experience with sprites yet, so... On to the second way: if I'm making it for mobile, what would I use? And what code would it be? Also what do you mean by "This makes you do the least amount of effort, but is generally bad for your future growth as a programmer."

Comment: First, you can always add classes, because anything you make as a separate symbol and set "Export for Actionscript" is actually a class. Second, you use `if (the box has been tapped)` clause, because text fields will no longer be able to be tapped, so that if you tap a text field that's above the box, the tap is registered to the box, so your action get triggered. And third, putting everything into the timeline has its own constraints which you can surpass by using both timeline and classes, and once you will get used to classes and OOP behavior, you then can master other programming languages